# Replace Git’s SHA with an index

Tags: git, version-control, commit

My colleague pointed out lately, that SVN refers to its commits with unique numbers. If I want to refer to a commit in Git, I know that I just have to copy a few of the SHA’s digits, but even if a project has some thousands of commits, an increasing number would be easier to remember or even type.

Is it possible to let Git list its commits like this?

```
0001 a258cb5 Latest commit
0002 373a4e2 previous one
0003 00f7c33 ...
0004 0bbc4da ...
0005 5b7eb09 ...
```

That way, you could refer to a commit with something like `HEAD~2` instead of `00f7c33`. Of course the number would change for every commit that is done, but I rarely refer to older commits, so the numbers would never be very large and easy to remember.

Comment: `HEAD~3` *does* refer to the commit three before the latest (labeled as 0004 in your example). See the specifying revisions section of `man git-rev-parse` http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_revisions So... unless the question is "how do I make `git log` number the commits so I don't have to count", I don't think there's much of a question at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git this does not make sense, as the commits are not really ordered. You can apply some changes from elsewhere and then forward merge others. I guess this applies to any distributed version control software.

Unless you manage your own list generated from the history, I'm afraid it's not possible.

If you look for a more readable way of uniquely identifying a change (not a number but some string that is human friendly), you can use the output of [`git describe`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-describe.html).
The format is:

```
last tag - # of commits since tag - g.id
```